# Power of two functions profiling

Tags: python

Running each 10,000 times, we get these:

```
Simple list lookup: 0.3219145839975681
Binary trick: 0.37199034500008565
```

Making the list lookup the faster solution. However, running it 100,000 times, we get these:

```
Simple list lookup: 3.265285526002117
Binary trick: 0.3752144949976355
```

Then the binary trick is clearly superior (as I would have expected).

*Why do I get such different results?*

The code follows:

```
from math import pow


POWERS = [pow(2, x) for x in range(0, 31)]


def list_lookup(x):
    """Is a power of two, via a simple list lookup."""
    return x in POWERS


def binary_trick(x):
    """Is a power of two, via a simple binary trick from stackoverflow."""
    return x > 0 and (int(x) & (int(x) - 1)) == 0


def test(func):
    """Tests the function "func" with lots of values."""
    data = [(pow(2, x), True) for x in range(0, 31)]
    data += [(pow(3, x), False) for x in range(1, 31)]  # Not one.
    for x, ex in data:
        assert func(x) is ex, "Debug: x={} → ex={}".format(x, ex)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    print("Simple list lookup: {}".format(
        timeit.timeit("test(list_lookup)",
                      number=100000,
                      globals=globals(),
                      setup="from __main__ import test")))
    print("Binary trick: {}".format(
        timeit.timeit("test(binary_trick)",
                      number=10000,
                      globals=globals(),
                      setup="from __main__ import test")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL:DR**

You have a typo. You are executing `test(list_lookup)` 100,000 times and `test(binary_trick)` 10,000 times.

---

Check this out:

```
times = 10000

print("Simple list lookup: {}".format(
    timeit.timeit("test(list_lookup)",
                  number=times,
                  globals=globals(),
                  setup="from __main__ import test")))
print("Binary trick: {}".format(
    timeit.timeit("test(binary_trick)",
                  number=times,
                  globals=globals(),
                  setup="from __main__ import test")))
```

outputs

```
Simple list lookup: 0.523675318
Binary trick: 0.6955866560000001
```

Changing `times` to `100000` outputs

```
Simple list lookup: 5.717076507
Binary trick: 6.923508393999999
```

`list_lookup` is always faster. Seems like the culprit is `binary_trick` calling `int(x)` twice.

Testing with `times = 100000` and `return x > 0 and (int(x) & (int(x) - 1)) == 0` we get

```
Simple list lookup: 3.343818478
Binary trick: 4.621393652
```

Changing `binary_trick` to

```
x = int(x)
return x > 0 and (x & (x - 1)) == 0
```

is making it 1 second faster:

```
Simple list lookup: 3.269909124
Binary trick: 3.1319104420000006
```

But we can make `list_lookup` faster by making it a `set_lookup`:

```
POWERS = {pow(2, x) for x in range(0, 31)}
```

And testing again for 100,000 times:

```
Simple list lookup: 1.443394541
Binary trick: 2.9750550150000006
```

Comment: Thank you. Yesterday was a special day for making stupid mistakes.